# Where to look-up what exceptions a BOTO3 function can throw?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I’m reading AWS Python docs such as [SNS Client Publish()](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) but can’t find the details of what exceptions a function can throw.

E.g., `publish()` can throw `EndpointDisabledException` but I can’t find this documented.

Where can I look up the list of exceptions a BOTO3 function can throw (for Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the list of exceptions for `publish(**kwargs)` -> [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) <- (bottom of `publish(**kwargs)` part)

Every exception is linked to its documentation

```
SNS.Client.exceptions.InvalidParameterException
SNS.Client.exceptions.InvalidParameterValueException
SNS.Client.exceptions.InternalErrorException
SNS.Client.exceptions.NotFoundException
SNS.Client.exceptions.EndpointDisabledException
SNS.Client.exceptions.PlatformApplicationDisabledException
SNS.Client.exceptions.AuthorizationErrorException
SNS.Client.exceptions.KMSDisabledException
SNS.Client.exceptions.KMSInvalidStateException
SNS.Client.exceptions.KMSNotFoundException
SNS.Client.exceptions.KMSOptInRequired
SNS.Client.exceptions.KMSThrottlingException
SNS.Client.exceptions.KMSAccessDeniedException
SNS.Client.exceptions.InvalidSecurityException
```

Comment: I'm no longer tied to this platform but, with this documentation added, your answer is tops. I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 8):

This is how to handle such exceptions:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import logging

try:
    response = platform_endpoint.publish(
        Message=json.dumps(message, ensure_ascii=False),
        MessageStructure='json')
    logging.info("r = %s" % response)
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'EndpointDisabled':
        logging.info('EndpointDisabledException thrown')
```

Comment: I see that this is how to handle them, but it doesn't answer your original question on where to find a function's possible thrown errors.

Answer (score 7):

Almost all exceptions are subclassed from `BotoCoreError`. I am not able to find a method to list all exceptions. Look at Botocore Exceptions file to get a list of possible exceptions. I can't find `EndpointDisabledException`. Are you using the latest version?

See: [Botocore Exceptions](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/exceptions.py)

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. I've gotten the exception from my AWS Lambda server and I'm not aware that I can choose boto3 versions on the server.  Thanks for the link. Searching that github repo I found one file https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/0387055fc157846d300c116f5da9d63e869814a6/botocore/data/sns/2010-03-31/service-2.json but it has limited details. The PHP docs have more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/namespace-Aws.Sns.html

Comment: @Carl This particular exception is thrown as a response from the API call. It is part of the `ClientError` Exception found in `exceptions.py`.

Comment: Thanks @Mangohero1 I have found it, implemented it, and now await SNS to throw it

Answer (score 0):

Use the client and then find the exception

example : if we are dealing with the cognito then

```
client = boto3.client(
        'cognito-idp',....)
try:
   some code .......
except client.exceptions.UsernameExistsException as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will generate an exhaustive list of exceptions from all supported services that it's boto3 client can throw.

````
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3

with open("README.md", "w") as f:
    f.write("# boto3 client exceptions\n\n")
    f.write(
        "This is a generated list of all exceptions for each client within the boto3 library\n"
    )
    f.write("""
```python
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
try:
  s3.create_bucket("example")
except s3.exceptions.BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou:
  raise
```\n\n""")
    services = boto3.session.Session().get_available_services()

    for service in services:
        f.write(f"- [{service}](#{service})\n")

    for service in services:
        f.write(f"### {service}\n")
        for _, value in boto3.client(
            service, region_name="us-east-1"
        ).exceptions.__dict__.items():
            for exception in value:
                f.write(f"- {exception}\n")
        f.write("\n")
````

Example output for S3 boto3 client:

- BucketAlreadyExists
- BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou
- InvalidObjectState
- NoSuchBucket
- NoSuchKey
- NoSuchUpload
- ObjectAlreadyInActiveTierError
- ObjectNotInActiveTierError

Reference: https://github.com/jbpratt/boto3-client-exceptions/blob/master/generate